# After using babel to compile, why does const、let、arrow function still exist？

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

[using babel to compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKWt1.png)

before

```js
let name="Alex";
const age=18;
const add=(x,y)=>x+y;
```

after using babel to compile

```js
"use strict";
let name = "Alex";
const age = 18;
const add = (x, y) => x + y;
```

I'm just really confused, why it didn't change anything at all.

Comment: Did you enable the `@babel/preset-env` by checking the checkbox in the left sidebar? babel will transpile your code according to your target environment.

Comment: yes, I enabled it, but still it didn't work. ![babel](https://gitee.com/zyxbj/image-warehouse/raw/master/pics/20210618143359.png)

Comment: What's specified in your `targets`?

Comment: @刘嘉琪 follow the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about targets you've selected. If you're only going to serve the app to the people using modern browsers, why bother shimming the syntax they totally understand anyway?

In this particular case it's not even about 'modern': it's about not being ancient. Both let/const and arrow functions support was introduced in browsers released in 2016 - five years ago.

With Babel, you usually configure your targets by setting up [@preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) and then choosing the list of targets either by some usage numbers:

```
{
  "targets": "> 0.25%, not dead"
}
```

... or directly, by providing an object specifing the minimum versions to support:

```
{
  "targets": {
    "chrome": "58",
    "ie": "11"
  }
}
```

Now it's Babel's responsibility to recognize the features the provided (explicitly or implicitly) list of browsers does support - and shim the features it doesn't.

You can play with this set up [in your browser](https://babeljs.io/repl#). For example, here's how your code is transformed when 'ie 11' is set up as a target:

[image: IE 11 Babel target]

... and here's how it looks for Chrome 91:

[image: Chrome 91 Babel target]